# Android: getting image locations

Tags: android, image, mediastore

I am looking for a way to find images on the SD card, or at least images taken by the camera.

The ideal solution would be getting a collection of file paths or URIs for the images. I guessing you can do this through the MediaStore I just can't figure out how.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After looking at more MediaStore examples I came up with this and it gets the job done.

```
protected ArrayList<Uri> GetImageList(boolean getThumbs) 
{       
    ArrayList<Uri> images = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    String columnType;  
    Uri contentType;                
    String[] columnNames;

    if (getThumbs)
    {
         columnType = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails._ID;
         contentType = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }
    else
    {
        columnType = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID;
        contentType = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    }

    columnNames = new String[]{columnType};             
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentType, columnNames, null, null, null);       
    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(columnType);

    for(int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++)
    {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = cursor.getInt(columnIndex);
        images.add(Uri.withAppendedPath(contentType, "" + id));
    }

    return images;
}
```

It returns the Uri of all the images or the Uri of the thumbnail of all the images on the sdcard.

Comment: It's better that you filter out photos using MediaStore.Images.Media.BUCKET_DISPLAY_NAME instead of reading the uri